# Equivalent of fst and snd for F# struct tuples?

Tags: f#

If I am using *reference* tuples, this compiles:

```
let plot(x: int, y: int) = ()
let point = 3, 4
plot(fst point, snd point)
```

However, if I am using *struct* tuples...

```
let plot(x: int, y: int) = ()
let point = struct (3, 4)
plot(fst point, snd point)
```

... I get the compiler error, `One tuple type is a struct tuple, the other is a reference tuple`

What should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[There's a `ToTuple()` extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tupleextensions.totuple?view=netframework-4.8#System_TupleExtensions_ToTuple__2_System_ValueTuple___0___1__) in `System.TupleExtensions` for `ValueTuple<T1, T2...>`.

You could just call:

```
plot (point.ToTuple())
```

As for `fst`, `snd`, they're bound to `System.Tuple<>`, so maybe you could define an alternative:

```
let fstv struct (a,_) =  a
let sndv struct (_,b) =  b
```

Comment: Thanks for the `ToTuple()` example. My plot function would have been a better example as `let plot (x: int) (y: int) = ()`. The `fstv` and `sndv` functions are nice!

Answer (score 3):

In F# 4.7, you must add another line to decompose the tuple.

```
let plot(x: int, y: int) = ()
let point = struct (3, 4)
let struct (x, y) = point
plot(x, y)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can declare new functions that work on struct tuples:

```ml
let fstv (struct (a, _)) = a
let sndv (struct (_, b)) = b
```

Usage:

```ml
let plot(x: int, y: int) = ()
let point = struct (3, 4)
plot(fstv point, sndv point)
```

If you want to get clever, you can use [SRTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/generics/statically-resolved-type-parameters) to make new `fst` and `snd` functions that work with *both* struct tuples and regular tuples:

```ml
type PairDispatcher = 
  | PairDispatcher with
    static member inline ($) (PairDispatcher,        (a, b)) = fun f -> f a b
    static member inline ($) (PairDispatcher, struct (a, b)) = fun f -> f a b
  
let inline fst x = (PairDispatcher $ x) (fun a _ -> a)
let inline snd x = (PairDispatcher $ x) (fun _ b -> b)
```

*(Taken from http://www.fssnip.net/7TT/title/Generic-fst-and-snd-functions)*

Then usage is:

```ml
let plot(x: int, y: int) = ()
let point = struct (3, 4)
plot(fst point, snd point)
```

I think on balance I would prefer to declare new functions.

Comment: What does SRTP mean in this context?  (Nevermind, "Statically resolved type parameters"